# Sum of orthogonal matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, numerical-linear-algebra

Consider the subspace $\mathbb{R}^m$ with usual inner product.Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ subspaces of $R^m$, $P_1\in M_m(\mathbb{R})$ the orthogonal projection matrix on $S_1$ and $P_2\in M_m(\mathbb{R})$ the orthogonal projection matrix on $S_2$ with the property that $P_1P_2=P_2P_1=0_m$

Show that $P_1+P_2$ is a orthogonal projection matrix and that $S_1$ and $S_2$ are orthogonal.

The first part imagine that there might be some special property of orthogonal matrix, but do not know how to show. In the second part I need to show that $\forall u\in S_1$ and $\forall v\in S_2$ $<u,v>=0?$

Comment: Compusider=(compute+consider) $(P_1+P_2)^2=P_1^2+P_1P_2+P_2P_1+P_2^2=P_1^2+P_2^2=P_1+P_2$. And recall, or prove that $P^2=P$ is the property of a projection.

Comment: Assume that $v\in S_1$ and $w=S_2$. Then $(v,w)=(P_1v,P_2w)=(P_2P_1v,w)=(0,w)=0$. That shows that $v,w$ are orthogonal.

Comment: Concerning the title of the question: Check the definition of "orthogonal matrix" and observe that the matrix of an orthogonal projection is usually not an orthogonal matrix. (If you say the terminology is ridiculous, I won't deny it.  I will say that the terminology has been around longer than I have, so (1) it's not my fault, and (2) there's probably nothing we can do about it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think @Alamos already gave a good proof though I think you may still need to verify the condition that $P_1+P_2$ is orthogonal.

A matrix $P$ is an orthogonal projection iff 
$$P^T= P, P^2 = P.$$

Since $P_1,P_2$ are orthogonal projection and $P_1P_2=P_2P_1 = 0$, verifying $(P_1+P_2)^2 = P_1+P_2$ and $(P_1+P_2)^T= P_1+P_2$ should not be too hard.

You do only need to show $\forall u\in S_1,v\in S_2, u^Tv =0$. Using the fact that $u = P_1u, v= P_2v$ (Since $P_1,P_2$ projects $\mathbb{R}^m$ on to $S_1,S_2$) and $P_1 P_2= P_1P_2=0$ and compute $u^Tv =(P_1u)^T(P_2v)=u^TP_1^TP_2v=u^TP_1P_2v$. You should be able to get the result.

Comment: How I can show that $P_1+P_2$ is projection orthogonal matrix on $W=S_1\bigoplus S_2$?

Comment: $P_1+P_2$ is already orthogonal as we have shown. Since $S_1,S_2$ are also orthogonal, the notation $\bigoplus$ makes sense. We need to show the image of $P_1+P_2$ is just $W=S_1 \bigoplus S_2$. Since $\forall w\in \mathbb{R}^m,(P_1+P_2)w =P_1w+P_2w$, and $P_1w \in S_1,P_2w\in S_2$, so we know the image of $P_1+P_2$ is include in $W$. As any element of $W$ could be written as $s_1+s_2$, $s_1\in S_1,s_2\in S_2$, and $(P_1+P_2)(s_1+s_2)=s_1+s_2$ (use $S_1,S_2$ orthogonal), we see that  $W$ is included in the image of $P_1+P_2$.

Comment: I'm having some trouble making proofs, you have some good reference linear algebra to tell me?

Comment: I am not sure what would would be a good reference linear algebra book. I learnt linear algebra from Robert J.Valenza's book: Linear Algebra- An introduction Abstract Mathematics. It is more conceptual and less computational which I think might be good if you want to avoid heavy computations.